# Runtime Error: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: java, html, applet, runtime-error, java-7

I'm trying to embed a Java applet that I wrote into an html file. Every time I run the file, I get a "java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError." I assume the problem is in the initialization function so I've included it below. If there is any other information/code that would be useful, let me know!

How to solve the `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`?

```
@Override
public void init(){   
    //Execute a job on the event-dispatching thread; creating this applet's GUI.
    try {  
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                enterLogin();
            }
        });
    } 
    catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        System.err.println("createGUI didn't complete successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: *"If there is any other information/code that would be useful, let me know!"*  1) The entire stack trace, copy/pasted into the question using code formatting. 2) An [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) A public URL to the broken applet..

Comment: Normally ExceptionInInitializationError is thrown from static code or initial values of fields; things that are calculated when the class is loaded before any code actually executes. Unless applets handle this differently your init() function is not the problem. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html

Comment: One of the various sources of `ExceptionInInitializerError` is to have a non `public` applet class.